# How to display missing ASP.NET MVC 1.0 VS Project Templates in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, templates

Visual Studio 2008 is not picking up the MVC 1.0 project templates. The MVC 1.0 release is installed on my system along with .NET 3.5 SP1 (pre-reqs).

I can't find MVC templates in the VS App's disk folders. The folders I'm searching are:

**VS 2008** (9.0)
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\, **subdirectory siblings**: ProjectTemplates/, ProjectTemplatesCache/ and Templates/

- Note: all templates shown in VS New Project dialog are found in here

**How do I find the project template and register it for Visual Studio, or is there a  workaround?**

---

*For reference, my other VS installs DO have the MVC templates...*

I have multiple version of VS installed including Express, 2005 Professional and 2008 Team. I'm only concerned about 2008 missing the MVC templates.

**VS 2005** (8.0)
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\VSTA\ItemTemplates\

- no MVC templates in here - good

**VS Other**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio

- no templates here - good

---

### Solution

After following accepted the links of the answer below, my MVC project templates appear
as shown [alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/6393/mvc2rc2vsts2008.jpg](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/6393/mvc2rc2vsts2008.jpg)

Comment: what is the problem? Template is installed on your system, and you just want mechanism to get it into visual studio -> new project -> available templates? in the development environment, means a setting to reference it?

Comment: this one might be helpful - http://forums.asp.net/t/1384062.aspx

Comment: @Mutant: good point. I rearranged the question to provide more immediate clarity about the problem.

Comment: @Mutant: I did download and install MVC separately as the links suggests. Problem is it's not made available in VS New Project templates.

Comment: Understood. I tried to install, for me even its same.

can you check this one if its helpful - http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkID=8900223

Comment: Still the same when I do everything in order suggested by release notes. I didn't have an older version installed so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Mutant: Found workaround. See below.

Comment: @Mutant:  I just realized you referenced the right answer back in your first comment. If you post it as an answer below I will remove mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one might be helpful - [forums.asp.net/t/1384062.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/t/1384062.aspx)

can you check this one as well - [go.microsoft.com/?LinkID=8900223](http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkID=8900223) (<< WORD doc download)

---

(John K/Feb 2012) I've inlined some parts of external answers referenced by the above links for context here. Visit the links for full context.

> GarlandGreene Member 128 Points 25 Posts Re: MVC templates in Visual
>   Studio Professional Edition 2008 Feb 12, 2009 04:24 PM|LINK
>
> **you have to install the ASP.Net MVC Framework Release Candidate, the
>   framework and the templates are not delivered with VS 2008. You can
>   download the Release Candidate from here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141184&clcid=0x409**